# adding serverless apis as a resource server AWS cognito AWS api gateway

Tags: amazon-cognito, serverless-framework, serverless

Hello I'm using serverless apis using aws api gateway lambda proxy, golang, and aws cognito

```yml
   events:
      - http:
          path: myendpoint
          method: get
          cors: true
          authorizer:
            name: my-authorizer
            arn: {COGNITO_POOL_ARN}

plugins:
  - serverless-domain-manager

custom:
  customDomain:
    domainName: mydomain.com
    basePath: mybasepath
    stage: ${self:provider.stage}
    createRoute53Record: true
```

this allows me to make request using the ID token to `mydomain.com/mybasepath/myendpoint` , I want to make it more standard and use access tokens.

it won't take the access token, API Gateway authorizer would bounce it off.

I added this as `Resource Server`  to the Cognito user pool settings

[image: Resourceserversetup]

in the `App client settings` I check the resource for the app client

[image]

I log out create a new session for the user, new tokens and i would get a 401 Unathorized
I think I'm following the documentation correctly as it is  [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-define-resource-servers.html#:%7E:text=%20Defining%20a%20Resource%20%20Server%20for%20Your,the%20identifier%20of%20your%20resource%20ser...%20More%20)  maybe I'm missing something else or perhaps because it is a serverless api it is a different set up that i need.

Any help or guidence is fully appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to secure your api with cognito there is no need to create scopes. Scopes don't grant authorizations to a user, they grant them to applications.

API Gateway Cognito Authorizer operates in basically three modes:

1. Allow both ID Token or Access Token (No token validation set & no scope set on the resource)
2. Allow ID Token (Token validation set to the `aud` claim/application ID & no scope set on the resource)
3. Allow Access Token (Token validation not set, scope set on the resource)

This is a consequence of the following in each case:

1. Both ID tokens & Access tokens are signed by Cognito signing keys so the authorizer can't tell them apart.
2. Only ID tokens contain the `aud` (audience) claims to perform the token validation against.
3. Only Access tokens include the `scope` claims to perform validation against.

Hope that clears things up. Don't get too hung up on scopes unless you know what you are using them for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  when i send an access token in the request the API gateway authorizer declines the request with a 401 access denied.  Where would i specify the kind of token the authorizer  accepts ? or change the mode it is operating ass ? Thanks in advance,

Comment: @FranciscoArias To allow access tokens exclusively make sure you do not have token validation set on your authorizer. Then set the scope on the API resources.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that's what i needed to do, I found the documentation 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html
And if you are using the serverless framework you will need this plugin 

https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-oauth-scopes

thank again brothe